# Bedeutung von "untauglicher Versuch"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Wenn es ihm(dem Innenminister) darum ging, die positiv engagierten Mitbürger zu stärken, war es ein **untauglicher Versuch**.

Wie ich gelesen habe, handelt es sich um einen juristischen Begriff. Ohne viel Hintergrundwissen auf dem Gebiet des Strafrechts oder über den Innenminister ist mir der Ausdruck jedoch nicht klar. Ist das eine zweite Bedeutung oder vielmehr ein metaphorischer Ausdruck?

Comment: Wo hast du gelesen, dass "untauglich" ein juristischer Begriff ist?

Comment: @IQV "Der untaugliche Versuch ist ein Begriff aus dem Allgemeinen Teil des deutschen Strafrechts." Hier z.B.

Comment: Der **untaugliche Versuch** ist ein juristischer Fachbegriff, der Einzug in die Alltagssprache gefunden hat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Untauglicher Versuch" mag auch ein juristischer Fachbegriff sein, mir als Muttersprachler ist er jedoch aus der Schriftsprache (also insb. Zeitungen/Zeitschriften) bekannt als Beschreibung für einen Versuch, der sich spätestens hinterher als "nicht hilfreich, da falsch konzipiert" erweist (mit einer starken Implikation, das der Sprecher den Versuch schon vorher so bewertet hat und der Handelnde zu dem gleichen Schluss hätte kommen können).